# How do you do negative random number (gamemaker studio)?

Tags: game-maker, gml, game-maker-language

Can you use

```
irandom(-10,10)
```

to generate negative numbers? Or does this function provides only number >=0?
There is no information in documentation of GML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few examples:

```
a = -1 * irandom(10);

a = -irandom(10);

a = irandom(20) - 10;

a = irandom_range(-10, 10);
```